# How can i return only the value with mongoose populate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm using [mongoose-paginate-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2) and also i'm using populate. It works but when i populate my field, the population returns an array and i want to put the name of the value inside of the field cajaID:

What i want to get:

```
{
    "_id": "5aa23958-06a9-4ff1-b614-d112d81b2eSi",
    "nombre": "Zone",
    "cajaID": "Caja grande"
}
```

What i get:

```
{
    "_id": "5aa23958-06a9-4ff1-b614-d112d81b2eSi",
    "nombre": "Zone",
    "cajaID": {
        "nombre": "Caja grande"
    }
}
```

My code:

```
await ZonesModel.paginate(query, { populate: {path: 'cajaID', select: { '_id': 0,'nombre':1}}}, function(err, doc) {

    if (err) {
        error = new Error(err);
        error.status = 500;
        throw error;
    }
    
    data = doc;
})
```

mongoose-paginate-v2 also has projection but when i want to access to the field "nombre" it doesn't work, just returns the value of the field which has the id of the another collection.

```
await model.paginate(query, { populate: {path: 'cajaID', select: { '_id': 0,'nombre':1}}, projection: {  caja: "$cajaID" }}, function(err, doc) {

    if (err) {
        error = new Error(err);
        error.status = 500;
        throw error;
    }
    
    data = doc;
})
```

This code return this:

```
{
    "_id": "5aa23958-06a9-4ff1-b614-d112d81b2eSi",
    "nombre": "Zone",
    "cajaID": {
        "nombre": "Caja grande"
    },
    "caja": "5aa23958-06a9-4ff1-b614-d112d81b2eBa" // id of the another collection but i can't access to the nombre field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that i can't filter after populate only with $lookup and $match. Therefore, in my frontend i'll use dropdowns for the ids and display the client's name and return the id of the selected user and pass it to my endpoint and it doesn't matter if i can't filter with the user's name because i can filter with their ids.

There is another alternative and that is by denormalizing the data, but I have data that doesn't changes very often, so the best alternative is with pupulate.